# mysqli insert - but only if not a duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, search, insert, mysqli

I'm a Java developer who just got handed the task of "some quick easy DB stuff" - except I don't know much about PHP/MySQL...I need to insert a record into a DB - but only if the email field doesn't match one that already exists in the DB. Here's what I've gleaned so far for my PHP code:

```
// Grab the values from the HTML form:
$newUserName = $_POST['newUserName'];
$newUserName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($newUserName);
$newUserEmail = $_POST['newUserEmail'];
$newUserEmail = $mysqli->real_escape_string($newUserEmail);

// Now search the DB to see if a record with this email already exists:
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM RegisteredUsersTable WHERE UserEmail = '$newUserEmail'");
```

Now I need to see if anything came back from that search - meaning the email already exists - and if so I need to alert the user, otherwise I can go ahead and insert the new info into the DB using:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO RegisteredUsersTable (UserName, UserEmail) VALUES ('".$newUserName."', '".$newUserEmail."')");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Put a `unique` constraint on the database. Then finally read from `$mysqli->error`, if there were any errors, there's a duplicate.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you want a better way to query? Or are you asking for some PHP code to glue it all together?

Comment: @MikeW: I believe he wants to insert some data into a users table, but not insert duplicate data (such as two rows with the same email).

Comment: RIght. I'm thinking the code I have so far is ok (maybe not the best, but ok) - so I'm just missing the code for the if statement that'll glue it all together.

Comment: Does my first comment work? If you do decide to put the validation on the database, that will make it so you only need to hit the database once (with PHP).

Comment: @DaveChen I understand the requirement, but it's not clear from his question what he wants us to provide. A subsequent comment seems to have clarified that.

Comment: @DaveChen, I don't know if your first comment works cause I have no idea how put a "unique" constraint on the DB. Was gonna Google that next. I also need to be able to email the user back with either a "success" or "failure" message. That's a must. Will the 'unique' approach let me do that?

Comment: @sirab333 - Yes you can easily see if it failed. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working from your code, this should point you in the right direction. there are, perhaps, better ways to structure your database that will make better use of it.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "iodine", "iodine","iodine");

// Grab the values from the HTML form:
/*
$newUserName = $_POST['newUserName'];
$newUserName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($newUserName);
$newUserEmail = $_POST['newUserEmail'];
$newUserEmail = $mysqli->real_escape_string($newUserEmail);
*/
$newUserName = "Test User";
$newUserEmail = "test4@example.com";

// Now search the DB to see if a record with this email already exists:
echo "SELECT * FROM RegisteredUsersTable WHERE UserEmail = '$newUserEmail'", "\n";
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM RegisteredUsersTable WHERE UserEmail = '$newUserEmail'");

if (!$result) {
  die($mysqli->error);
}
echo "num_rows = ".$result->num_rows."\n";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   echo "Duplicate email\n";
   // do something to alert user about non-unique email
} else {
  $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO RegisteredUsersTable (UserName, UserEmail) VALUES ('".$newUserName."', '".$newUserEmail."')");
  if ($result === false) {echo "SQL error:".$mysqli->error;}
}

?>
```

Comment: if I use this code, do I still have to first `ALTER IGNORE` the table as per the answer posted by @hellohellosharp?

Comment: No - this is based on your original structure, just to give you some PHP glue. @hellohellosharp has addressed a possible race condition caused by the two queries on the database - his is a better structure for the data, but the PHP you'd use would be different with only one query to execute.

Comment: ok, I guess I'll have to try both approaches and see what's better? For what its worth, I don't expect this DB to be all that big. Maybe like 10k users - should I still worry about races and performance issues?

Comment: My general approach is to code out a problem before it occurs, so yes, you should worry. In practice, you're unlikely to get a problem unless somebody is malicious.

Comment: Its not working. I implemented your suggested code but have since successfully inserted entries with the exact same email 3 times already ...Noticed there was a missing ")" on the `die($mysqli->error;` line - are there other possible typos/omissions in your posted code by any chance?

Comment: That's what I get for posting code I haven't had time to check over thoroughly. The line `if ($mysqli->num_rows > 0) {` should read `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {`. I have posted a whole new version in the answer that includes some debugging lines. This runs on my development system (PHP 5.4, MySQL 5.5), and behaves as it's supposed to.

Comment: Yeah, I actually figured it out (I put in a little intermediary var like this: `$numRowsFound = $result->num_rows;` between the `if-die` statement and the `num_rows > 0` statement because that just looked like it would make sense - and it worked, but your new code is obviously good. Thanks very much - I marked it as the right answer.

Answer (score 6):

Consider putting a `unique` index on this particular table. The following code will add the index and remove any current duplicates:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `RegisteredUsersTable` ADD UNIQUE INDEX unique_email (`UserEmail`);
```

Once this is added, use `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. They will only preform the insert if there is no duplicates.

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO RegisteredUsersTable (UserName, UserEmail) VALUES ('".$newUserName."', '".$newUserEmail."')");
```

Mysql will throw an error because the email is already in the database. However, the IGNORE command is telling the script to not pay any attention to errors for this query because, in this case, you expect it for a duplicate row.

Also, there is a way to alert your user with a failure or success message, even with `INSERT IGNORE`. Use MYSQL `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. If an ID was given, it was inserted. If not, then the email was already there (or there was another error).

Comment: +1, exactly what I said, you can also mention that this method is better than checking manually with another query for two reasons. 1. It's not [racy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), 2. It only hits the database once.

Comment: @DaveChen - I agree, and personally always use *INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE*. INSERT IGNORE is much easier to understand though which is why I used it as an example. OP should research both and make their own decision.

Comment: @hellohellosharp - this looks good, but so does the answer given by Mike W - so how am I supposed to decide? :-) I want to mark both your answers as correct (which is impossible of course) but I need to try and implement them first...what to do?

Answer (score 0):

As for your first query, to soften the load on servers, use count() instead.

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT count(*) FROM RegisteredUsersTable WHERE UserEmail = '$newUserEmail'");
```

This way, you can just check if you've gotten a result higher than 1. If the result is greater than 1, then the username exists (Since a row was returned).

To check the data returned, you need to simply execute the statement, then fetch the results. Part of the fun is learning, so here's the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)